# Are the fan_timer fields of a thermostat returned when the fan is activated by an every day event?

Tags: nest-api

Are the fan_timer fields returned when the fan is activated by an Every Day event?

I've simulated the fan timer fields being returned as true with a timeout when a timer is activated on a fan. Do these fields behave the same when a fan is activated from an Every Day event?

I can't replicate using the simulator so I'm guessing no. Just wondered if it is a quirk of a simulated thermostat or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it only triggers when the timer is manually started.

Comment: Thanks urman. Do any other api fields change when a fan is activated through an every day event?

Comment: Not necessarily, but the hvac_state object should update heating or cooling for all events.